# How to exclude built-in rules in a custom plugin?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-plugin

I'm developing a new plugin for SonarQube supporting a new language, but when I included this plugin there were a couple of built-in rules such as:

- Branches should have sufficient coverage by tests
- Failed unit tests should be fixed
- Lines should have sufficient coverage by tests
- Skipped unit tests should be either removed or fixed and etc.

For my new language testing doesn't have any sense and I'd like to exclude them. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, those "Common" rules are available by default on all languages directly from SonarQube itself, and cannot currently (as of 6.6, at least) be removed.